# IIF(COUNT) expression and GROUP BY not returning expected result

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SSMS for a select statement where I have a number of tables that are joined. One of the fields need to be flagged as either 'M' or 'N' depending on the outcome of an IIF(COUNT(*) that I use.

The select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT
,   AcctChar.Chr1Nme             AS [Submitted For Party]   
,   P.LOCAL_CURR_CDE             AS [Notional Currency 1]
,   T.PortfolioCode              AS [Acct_ID]
,   T.IAMID                      AS [IAMID]
,   iif(count(*) > 1, 'M', 'N')  AS [ActionType]
,   T.Quantity                   AS [Quantity]
,   p.FLD1_AMT                   AS [Notional]
,   I.ISS_TMS                    AS [EffectiveDte]

from [dbo].[POSITION] AS p

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Trades] AS T
                    ON    T.PortfolioCode = P.ACCT_ID

INNER JOIN InfoPortal.dbo.ISSUE_DG AS i         
                     ON   i.instr_id = p.instr_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN infoportal.dbo.DW_AcctCharDG AS AcctChar
                    ON AcctChar.AcctId = p.acct_ID

GROUP BY
    AcctChar.Chr1Nme
,   P.LOCAL_CURR_CDE
,   T.PortfolioCode
,   T.IAMID 
,   T.Quantity
,   p.FLD1_AMT  
,   I.ISS_TMS
```

The above query return the correct number of results but the [ActionType] is incorrect. It shows all records as 'N' which is incorrect. I need the iif(count(*) > 1, 'M', 'N') statement to identify if there are any records in T (using the unique combination of T.PortfolioCode and T.IAMID) to identify if there is only a single record in T (in that case ActionType = 'N' or if there are > 1 records in T with the same PortfolioCode and IAMID combination then flag those as 'M'.

If I only GROUP BY T.PortfolioCode and T.IAMID I get the following error:
Column 'AcctChar.Chr1Nme' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. If I add AcctChar.Chr1Nme to the GROUP BY it just continues with the next field in the Select statement with the same error.

How can I configure the iif(COUNT) clause for [ActionType] or the GROUP BY to only look at the T.PortfolioCode and T.IAMID combination, and not all the fields in the select statement, to determine uniqueness in terms of the T.PortfolioCode and T.IAMID combination only?

Comment: You've tagged this `mysql` but it seems to relate to `mssql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to run it myself, this is a bit of a guess, but I think you need the count in a subquery:

```
SELECT
,   AcctChar.Chr1Nme             AS [Submitted For Party]   
,   P.LOCAL_CURR_CDE             AS [Notional Currency 1]
,   T.PortfolioCode              AS [Acct_ID]
,   T.IAMID                      AS [IAMID]
,   T.ActionType                 AS [ActionType]
,   p.FLD1_AMT                   AS [Notional]
,   I.ISS_TMS                    AS [EffectiveDte]

from [dbo].[POSITION] AS p

INNER JOIN (select    PortfolioCode  
    ,   IAMID
    ,   iif(count(*) > 1, 'M', 'N')  AS [ActionType]
    from Trades group by PortfolioCode, IAMID
) AS T

INNER JOIN InfoPortal.dbo.ISSUE_DG AS i         
                     ON   i.instr_id = p.instr_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN infoportal.dbo.DW_AcctCharDG AS AcctChar
                    ON AcctChar.AcctId = p.acct_ID
```